PowerBI - How to sort 100% stacked bar chart by one individual number
Trying to sort this chart in PowerBI Desktop Version: 2.128.952.0 64-bit (April 2024)
Want to sort by highest green number at the top
Tried sorting by Axis, but it only sorted the names
Tried sorting the answers, but that didn't work either.
Nothing seems to work.

By "this chart", did you mean to provide some source code in the question?
